# Android kotlin casting warning

Tags: android, kotlin, casting, singleton

I am using singleton design pattern but I am getting below casting warning how to resolve it.

> Unchecked cast: DownloadManager<*>? to DownloadManager

At Line -

> instance as? DownloadManager ?: DownloadManager(

Code

```
inline fun <reified OfflineContentMeta> DownloadManager() = DownloadManager.createInstance(
)

class DownloadManager<OfflineContentMetaData> private constructor(


) : DownloadProvider {

companion object {

    private var instance: DownloadManager<*>? = null

    const val MSG =
        "Tried to re-init this download manager"

    fun <OfflineContentMeta> createInstance(
       
    ): DownloadManager<OfflineContentMeta>? {
        return if (instance == null) {
            synchronized(this) {
                instance as? DownloadManager<OfflineContentMeta> ?: DownloadManager(
                   
                ).also {
                    instance = it
                }
            }
        } else {
            instance?.let {
                throw Exception(
                    message = MSG,
                )
            }

        }
    }
}

 }
```

Comment: Why don't you just let a dependency injection framework like Hilt handle the object creation for you? It automatically handles Singletons correctly.

Comment: Also, the provided code behaves differently than what you describe: The top-level factory function and the private constructor produce a "*Conflicting overloads*" error: They have the same signature, so the compiler cannot decide which one to call. When the function is removed, there still is another problem: "*Not enough information to infer type variable OfflineContentMetaData*" for `instance as? DownloadManager<OfflineContentMeta> ?: DownloadManager()`. If you fix this everything looks good, but I never encounter the error you describe. Can you please make sure you posted the right code?

Comment: Kotlin has built-in singletons with `object` keyword. What is the purpose of type argument here?

Comment: A generic type argument for a singleton makes no sense.